# Getting OleVariant (TClientDataset.Data) from Evaluator

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, toolsapi

Is it possible to evaluate an OleVariant of type varArray (Data of TClientDataset) using Delphi evaluator? I'm trying to build a Debugger Visualizer, using ToolsApi, for this kind of type. I work in an application that uses this extensively to transport data from client to server, and this would be really nice! I tried to work with pointers, evaluating `TVarData(variable).VType` and `TVarData(variable).VArray`, and then casting then to pointers, but the pointer is not valid in the api.

When I have a TClientDataset variable in the debugging code, this is not necessary, because we already have an extention using ToolApi to visualize the dataset (calling SaveToFile in evaluator). But we have too many code that have only the data variable.

So my question is: is there a way to do this with multiple evaluations, like converting the varArray to string and then unserialize the result in the api (visualizer)?
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58771186/6137384) that could convert the OleVariant to string, but does not say anything about converting back to OleVariant.

I'm using [this](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/code-snippet-ide-debug-visualizer-plugin-for-generic-and-template-types) post as an example of a visualizer.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you would regard as an answer.  If you're asking whether its possible to take an OleVariant containing CDS data and display it e.g. in a DBGrid, yes, that would be possible and is fairly trivial to do.  The trickier bit might be wiring it into Delphi's debugging environment bc I'm not sure that a debugger visualizer is the ideal place but worth a try though ...

Comment: No, I am not asking about take the OleVariant data and display somewhere, I know that is trivial. I am asking about whether its possible to evaluate it in debug time. "Serialize", just using the evaluator. That is necessary for manipulate it in the ToolsApi

Comment: My expected answer is if this is possible. If it is, how I could do it

Comment: Then, I'm afraid I am even less clear what you want.  What exactly do you mean by "serialize"?

Comment: Get the content of the OleVariant. The evaluator does not work directly with OleVariant, just return "Variant array of Byte". I want to get this content using the ToolsApi, but there I can only use the evaluator. So I am asking if there is some way to do this. I used the word "serialize" because this is a kind of serialization, because after that I would need to "unserialize" to a local OleVariant, in the ToolsApi package

Comment: Imagine that you are debugging an application, and in some method you have an OleVariant variable (data of cds), and you want to see the content of it. You'd have to edit the code to write to a cds to see it, save to a file, something like that. What I want to do is a Visualizer for this situation.

Comment: I could use some variant functions (VarIsArray, VarArrayDimCount, VarArrayLowBound, VarArrayHighBound, VarToStr), that work in the evaluator, to get the string of the OleVariant, but I dont know if I could "unserialize" this string back to an OleVariant